# Explicit ack to JMS using Alpakka

Tags: jms, akka, akka-camel, alpakka

I am currently using `Akka-Camel` for integrating my Akka based application with various message queues.
Now that I want to upgrade to the latest version of Akka I see that this integration is now deprecated.

I have tried using `alpakka-jsm` integration but am unable to see whether I can perform explicit `ack` to the message queues once I have processed the message. Does this functionality exist in this new component?

Answer (score 1):

Alpakka [0.15](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/0.15/jms.html#receiving-s-messages-from-a-jms-provider-with-client-acknowledgement) makes the acknowledgement mode in the JMS connector configurable. An example that's adapted from the linked documentation:

```scala
val jmsSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] = JmsSource(
  JmsSourceSettings(connectionFactory)
    .withQueue("myqueue")
    .withAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.ClientAcknowledge)
)

val result = jmsSource
  .map {
    case textMessage: TextMessage =>
      val text = textMessage.getText
      textMessage.acknowledge()
      text
  }
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
```